# How to import Apache Commons Lang source file to Eclipse in order to edit its code?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I have been trying hard to import the source code of Apache Commons Lang 3.5 in a way to edit its code to add some functionality.

I have done a lot of research over the web regarding that, but most of the topic were on how to import Apache Commons Lang 3.5 JAR or Binary file to Eclipse, which did not allow me to edit the source code (i.e. read only access).

My question is: how could I edit the source code of Apache Commons Lang 3.5 in Eclipse?

Comment: It's all [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang).

Comment: Most of the time you don't actually need to edit the source of such a well know and established project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source can be found here.

https://github.com/apache/commons-lang

Assuming you have the Egit plugin in your Eclipse install then:

Window > Show View > Git > Git Repositories

- Select the 'Clone a Git Repository and import existing Maven Project' button
- Set this as the URL: https://github.com/apache/commons-lang.git

The repository should now be cloned to the selected location and imported to your workspace.

One done right click on the root of the project and Run As > 'Maven Install'.

Everything should build without any issues.

If you don't have the Egit plugin then you can install as detailed here:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/